# How to determine the number of already created entities of a give type in a settlement's storage?

Tags: fallout-4

So when you go around a settlement and clean it up, you can store some things instead of salvaging them (tab in settlement edit mode for the computer).  Once stored, when you go to build that type of entity again, it will place build it  without using any resources until you have used up all the ones in storage (it will also not award experience points for building them, as you aren't making new ones).  Once you have used up all the ones in storage, it will begin building them by deducting from your resources and awarding experience.

My problem is that I don't see any indicator of how many I have left before it will cost resources.  Where can I check so I don't go wasting resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They appear as a number in the build menu when in Workshop mode, overlaying the item you've got in storage.

[image: storing items]

Comment: This is correct.  One catch I found on testing.  It only shows up for the item you currently have selected.  So in your example screenshot, you could have 0 or 2 of each of the other generators but it would still be blank in either case until you selected it.